# How do I run an animation with pyglet only one time?

Tags: python, pyglet

I am generating animation sequences as my program runs, and I would like the code to just run the sequence one time and then rest. How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
window = pyglet.window.Window()

mouth = pyglet.resource.image('pic.png')

raw = pyglet.image.load('pic.png')
raw_seq = pyglet.image.ImageGrid(raw, 1, 7)

animation = pyglet.image.Animation.from_image_sequence(raw_seq, .11, True)
mouth2 = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(animation)

w = window.width
h = window.height

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    mouth2.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyglet.app.run()
```

To clearify: My raw_seq is a list of 7 frames (as I understand it), and I want that sequence to just be animated one time.

Answer (score 2):

`animation = pyglet.image.Animation.from_image_sequence(raw_seq, .11, False)`
that will set loop=False and only run one time